# POST vars generate general error with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to pass vars trough a form with post method, it generates the following codeigniter error "GENERAL_ERROR".

Comment: Hi, this error can be easily resolved using GENERAL_ANSWER. Good luck.

Comment: Does this form has an action attribute?

Comment: Yes it have the following action action="/search" which call controller "search"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example for you

controllers/test_form.php

```
<?php
class Test_form extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {
            print_r($this->input->post());
        }

        $this->load->view('test_form');
    }
}
```

views/test_form.php

```
<form action="test_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test_field_one" />
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Maybe you have a typo somewhere in your code, without seeing it though I'm stabbing things in the dark.

Comment: There is no special code, only a simple form (method="post") with an input. The error is generated when I send the form.

Comment: here is the error with your code : http://disquesoffice.bluesys2.ch/test_form. I think I should have a config error

Comment: I have never,  ever seen that error before. It doesn't even look like a codeigniter error. Are you sure its installed correctly?

Comment: Ok I tried your search form and see that the same thing is happening. As I said i have personally never seen this happen before. Could it possibly be a custom 404 page? I can't even think what would cause this to happen.